# Why is splice not working in mongoose and why is splice also not working properly?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const items = require('../jsons/items.json');
const InvModel = require('../models/inventorySchema')

module.exports = {
    info: {
        name: "deduct",
        description: "Test command",
    },
    name: "deduct",
    description: "Test command",
    async execute(Discord, client, interaction, inv){
        let newItem = items.itemList.find(x => x._id == "Apple")
       
        function getCount(_id) {
            const existingItem = inv.inventory.find((item) => item._id === _id);

            return existingItem?.count ?? 5;
        }
            {
            let counter = getCount(newItem._id);
            await InvModel.findOneAndUpdate({
                userId: interaction.user.id,
                "inventory._id": newItem._id
            }, {
                $set: {
                    "inventory.$.count": counter - 5
                }
            })
        }
        const index = inv.inventory.indexOf({id: newItem._id, count: 0});
        if (index > -1) { 
            inv.inventory.splice(index, 1); 
        }
        
        await interaction.reply(`**Deducted 5 apples from your inventory**`);
    }
}
```

Now, what this code does is that it deducts 5 from the amount of apples in your inventory. (The inventory is an array). It's a simple thing. But, the problem here is that if the amount of an item in the inventory is exactly 5, and it deducts 5, the item is still in the inventory, with a count of 0. So I tried to splice the item from the array if the count is 0.

**This is what I came up with:**

```
 const index = inv.inventory.indexOf({id: newItem._id, count: 0});
        if (index > -1) { 
            inv.inventory.splice(index, 1); 
        }
```

This did not work either. How do I make it so that if the count of an item in the inventory is zero, It will never show in the array/inventory?

Answer (score 0):

to remove item with criteria from array you can use js array.filter method

[developper mozilla array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

`const newArray = inv.inventory.filter(item => item.count !== 0)`